# Invalidating caches and restarting doesn't fix the BR import bug...Databinding issue

Tags: java, android, android-databinding

Almost finished this app and running into compile time error with the data binding aspect in my `Movie` class I've extended `BaseObserver` and on trying to build project I can't import BR for the         `notifyPropertyChanged(BR.voteCount);`
 on a setter. I can't see the issue but if I try compile and it were to get passed that it crashes on launch with the following stack trace.

[image: stackTrace]

I figured if it's a problem with the generated code then how do I tinker with that???

Really puzzled! Any help appreciated.

I've added dependencies can't see no issues there....

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tmdbclient"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0"

    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    // alternatively - just ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version" // For Kotlin use lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx

    annotationProcessor 'com.android.databinding:compiler:2.3.0'

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:29.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:29.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'

}
```

---

Model

```
package com.example.tmdbclient.model;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.widget.ImageView;


import androidx.databinding.BaseObservable;
import androidx.databinding.Bindable;
import androidx.databinding.BindingAdapter;
import androidx.databinding.BR;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.tmdbclient.R;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Movie extends BaseObservable implements Parcelable
{

    @SerializedName("vote_count")
    @Expose
    private Integer voteCount;
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("video")
    @Expose
    private Boolean video;
    @SerializedName("vote_average")
    @Expose
    private Double voteAverage;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("popularity")
    @Expose
    private Double popularity;
    @SerializedName("poster_path")
    @Expose
    private String posterPath;
    @BindingAdapter("posterPath")
    public void loadImage(ImageView imageView, String imageURL) {

        String imagePath = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + imageURL;

        Glide.with(imageView.getContext())
                .load(imagePath)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
                .into(imageView);



    }


    @SerializedName("original_language")
    @Expose
    private String originalLanguage;
    @SerializedName("original_title")
    @Expose
    private String originalTitle;
    @SerializedName("genre_ids")
    @Expose
    private List<Integer> genreIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    @SerializedName("backdrop_path")
    @Expose
    private String backdropPath;
    @SerializedName("adult")
    @Expose
    private Boolean adult;
    @SerializedName("overview")
    @Expose
    private String overview;
    @SerializedName("release_date")
    @Expose
    private String releaseDate;
    public final static Parcelable.Creator<Movie> CREATOR = new Creator<Movie>() {


        @SuppressWarnings({
                "unchecked"
        })
        public Movie createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Movie(in);
        }

        public Movie[] newArray(int size) {
            return (new Movie[size]);
        }

    }
            ;

    protected Movie(Parcel in) {
        this.voteCount = ((Integer) in.readValue((Integer.class.getClassLoader())));
        this.id = ((Integer) in.readValue((Integer.class.getClassLoader())));
        this.video = ((Boolean) in.readValue((Boolean.class.getClassLoader())));
        this.voteAverage = ((Double) in.readValue((Double.class.getClassLoader())));
        this.title = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
        this.popularity = ((Double) in.readValue((Double.class.getClassLoader())));
        this.posterPath = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
        this.originalLanguage = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
        this.originalTitle = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
        in.readList(this.genreIds, (java.lang.Integer.class.getClassLoader()));
        this.backdropPath = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
        this.adult = ((Boolean) in.readValue((Boolean.class.getClassLoader())));
        this.overview = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
        this.releaseDate = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
    }

    public Movie() {
    }


    @Bindable
    public Integer getVoteCount() {
        return voteCount;
    }

    public void setVoteCount(Integer voteCount) {
        this.voteCount = voteCount;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.voteCount);
    }


    @Bindable
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id)
    {
        this.id = id;
        notifyPropertyChanged(com.example.tmdbclient.BR.id);


    }

    @Bindable
    public Boolean getVideo() {
        return video;
    }

    public void setVideo(Boolean video) {

        this.video = video;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.video);
    }

    @Bindable
    public Double getVoteAverage() {
        return voteAverage;
    }

    public void setVoteAverage(Double voteAverage) {

        this.voteAverage = voteAverage;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.voteAverage);
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {

        this.title = title;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.title);
    }

    @Bindable
    public Double getPopularity() {
        return popularity;
    }

    public void setPopularity(Double popularity) {

        this.popularity = popularity;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.popularity);
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getPosterPath() {
        return posterPath;
    }

    public void setPosterPath(String posterPath) {

        this.posterPath = posterPath;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.posterPath);
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getOriginalLanguage() {
        return originalLanguage;
    }

    public void setOriginalLanguage(String originalLanguage) {
        this.originalLanguage = originalLanguage;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.originalLanguage);
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getOriginalTitle() {
        return originalTitle;
    }

    public void setOriginalTitle(String originalTitle) {

        this.originalTitle = originalTitle;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.originalTitle);
    }

    @Bindable
    public List<Integer> getGenreIds() {
        return genreIds;
    }

    public void setGenreIds(List<Integer> genreIds) {

        this.genreIds = genreIds;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.genreIds);
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getBackdropPath() {
        return backdropPath;
    }

    public void setBackdropPath(String backdropPath) {

        this.backdropPath = backdropPath;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.backdropPath);
    }

    @Bindable
    public Boolean getAdult() {
        return adult;
    }

    public void setAdult(Boolean adult) {

        this.adult = adult;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.adult);
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getOverview() {
        return overview;
    }

    public void setOverview(String overview) {
        this.overview = overview;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.overview);
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getReleaseDate() {
        return releaseDate;
    }

    public void setReleaseDate(String releaseDate) {

        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.releaseDate);
    }


    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeValue(voteCount);
        dest.writeValue(id);
        dest.writeValue(video);
        dest.writeValue(voteAverage);
        dest.writeValue(title);
        dest.writeValue(popularity);
        dest.writeValue(posterPath);
        dest.writeValue(originalLanguage);
        dest.writeValue(originalTitle);
        dest.writeList(genreIds);
        dest.writeValue(backdropPath);
        dest.writeValue(adult);
        dest.writeValue(overview);
        dest.writeValue(releaseDate);
    }

    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

---

activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    >
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout 
    android:id="@+id/swipe"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.MainActivity"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvMovies"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
</RelativeLayout>

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</layout>
```

---

activity_movie

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="movie"
            type="com.example.tmdbclient.model.Movie" />

    </data>

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".view.MovieActivity">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:theme="@style/Widget.Design.AppBarLayout">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/ctMovie"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivMovieLarge"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                        bind:posterPath="@{movie.posterPath}" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />


            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


        <include
            android:id="@+id/secondary_layout"
            layout="@layout/content_movie"
            bind:secondaryMovie="@{movie}" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</layout>
```

---

content_movie

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="secondaryMovie"
            type="com.example.tmdbclient.model.Movie" />

    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context=".view.MovieActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_movie">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:showIn="@layout/activity_movie">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvMovieTitle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:padding="16dp"
                        android:text="@{secondaryMovie.title}"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvRating"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:padding="16dp"
                        android:text="@{Double.toString(secondaryMovie.voteAverage)}"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvMovieTitle"

                        />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvSynopsis"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:padding="16dp"
                        android:text="@{secondaryMovie.overview}"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvRating"

                        />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvRelease"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:padding="16dp"
                        android:text="@{secondaryMovie.releaseDate}"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvSynopsis"

                        />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</layout>
```

---

movie_list_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="movie"
            type="com.example.tmdbclient.model.Movie" />

    </data>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cvMovie"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="3dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivMovie"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    bind:posterPath="@{movie.posterPath}" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/ivMovie"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:text="@{movie.title}"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvRating"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tvTitle"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:text="@{Double.toString(movie.voteAverage)}"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you should do is

Change these lines

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:29.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:29.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.0.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.design:design:1.0.0'
```

Problem is with your `loadImage` method of `Movie` class. Define it static and it should work.

Comment: Thanks Derek, did that, still can't find symbol BR .Cleaned project rebuilt same error. How will I track it down will it be in the XML?

Comment: add your xml and model.

Comment: added xml and model.

Comment: Problem is with your `loadImage` method of `Movie` class. Define it static and it should work.